# How can I rotate multiple objects in their LOCAL axis?

Tags: modeling, objects, mathematics

Hello blender friends.

I would like to rotate multiple objects by random, but in their LOCAL axis. NOT global.
I already know the random transform function for objects, but it's working always for the global axis only.

Bit I would like to rotate random around the local z axis e.g.

In Softimage XSI in 2005 it was possible to type in mathematical functions into the input fields. There were a function like this **r(1,10)**. It has generated a random value between 1 and 10.

Is this possible without using python?

Comment: Try with proportional editing

Answer (score 7):

[image: Many object]

There's a simple method for that in Blender.Here The couple of Cubes represent your Multiple Objects.

1. Select one of the  object in your scene. (The nearby objects to the selection will have more influence of Random Rotation).
   [image]
2. Change the Pivot Point to Individual.(So cubes will be rotated on their Local Axis)
   [image]
3. Press 'O' in keyboard (To turn on Proportional Editing) & set it to Random.
   [image]

More Info while pressing R for rotate a circle will appear that represents the effective Radius for the Random Rotation that can be changed by (Mouse Wheel) or (Page Up or Page Down)

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 5):

To rotate around multiple local origins, change the pivot point to "individual origins." The pivot point menu is shown in the picture below. I know this doesn't solve the problem of how to rotate at random, but I hope this helps at least a little.

[image]Go to edit mode,